# Analytic Functions and Equicontinuity

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $r > 0$, $R > 0$, and assume that the power series with real coefficients
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n,m = 0}^{\infty} a_{n,m} x^{n} y^{m}
\end{equation}
is absolutely convergent for every real $x, y$ such that $|x| < r$, $|y| < R$. Then you can rearrange the terms of the series in ascending powers of $x$ as
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} f_n(y) x^{n},
\end{equation}
where the function $f_n:(-R,R) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are analytic functions. My question is the following. Can you choose $\delta \in (0,R)$ such that the familty of functions $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$, when restricted to $[-\delta, \delta]$, turns out be equicontinuous?

I think the answer is negative, but I have no counterexample.
Thank you very much in advance for your invaluable help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is negative:

Consider:

- $r= \frac{1}{2}$
- $R=1$
- $a_{n,m}=2^n$

Now, for every $-\frac{1}{2}<x<\frac{1}{2}, -1<y<1$:

$\sum_{n,m = 0}^{\infty} a_{n,m} x^{n} y^{m}=
\sum_{n,m = 0}^{\infty}2^nx^{n} y^{m}=
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{2^n}{1-y}x^{n}=
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-y}{(2x)}^{n}=\frac{1}{(1-y)(1-2x)}
$

and is converges. You can see that:

$f_n(y)
=\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty} a_{n,m} y^{m}
=\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}2^ny^{m}
=\frac{2^n}{1-y}$

and it is not equicontinuous for every $0<\delta<1$.

Comment: Thank you very much Sagi for having kindly replied to my answer. You should only replace the $\leq$ signs with $<$ signs in the inequalities about $x$ and $y$. Thank you again very much!!

Comment: You are welcomed 